# "go test" reports incorrect statement coverage

Tags: go

I have a [package](https://github.com/suzaku/dummage) with only two Go file: one defines the main function and the other is for the tests.

Now assume that I have `cd` into this package and run the following command:

```
$ go test -cover
PASS
coverage: 41.8% of statements
ok      github.com/suzaku/dummage       0.010s
```

As you can see, this works correctly.

But I want to generate a HTML report, so after some googling I use the following command:

```
$ go test -run=Coverage -coverprofile=c.out github.com/suzaku/dummage
ok      github.com/suzaku/dummage       0.010s  coverage: 1.8% of statements
```

Note that this time the coverage drops to 1.8%.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need that `-run=Coverage` flag in your go test? This means it will only run tests that match `Coverage`. If you just want to generate a cover profile for that tests, run `go test -coverprofile c.out github.com/suzaku/dummage`. Then you may run `go tool cover -html c.out` to see the HTML report.

If you added `-run=Coverage` on purpose, then it's expected behavior - the amount of code that runs during `-run=Coverage` is much less than while running all tests, and the test coverage is calculated for the entire package.